# separate Last Name, First Name and Middle Initial in three different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, text-parsing

I have a file which contains Last Name, First Name MI for about 5000 people. 
I need to split them in 3 different columns. 
The issue I am facing is , that sometimes there are more than 1 first names, for example I have a person as Davis, Mary Ann L.
I want Davis in one column.
Mary Ann in another column and L in the 3rd column. Basically check if after the comma the number of characters is greater than 1. If it is greater than 1 then consider it as first name. If number of characters is equal to 1, then consider it Middle Initial.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: Post some sample data in table format

Comment: Put the comments from Jorick Spitzen and YVXS 4 and edit your question to include the requested information. An informed, focussed answer will be likely be provided shortly.

Comment: I cant do the "Text to column" because in cases where first names are like "Mary Ann", those will split in two different columns. I want Mary Ann in one column because both Mary and Ann are first names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would do a first approach by using the **"Text to Column"** command. Just mark the whole column, then choose Data -> Text to Column. Choose "delimited", then next, then select "Space".

After this, I would look through the processed data and get a picture. I assume that most records will be ok already now. And those records which are exceptions to the standard should be easily identifyable. You could even **filter** for them.

Only then, in a third step, I'd write a formula which processes the columns you have created in the first step.

Or, possibly a formula is not necessary at all. Possibly you can just easily filter and process some of the exceptions manually.

Comment: I cant do the "Text to column" because in cases where first names are like "Mary Ann", those will split in two different columns. I want Mary Ann in one column because both Mary and Ann are first names.

Comment: I would still do it in a first approach and then look how many exceptions you have at all. Also, after you have split it, it is much easier to process with formulas. *[SQLPolice never downvotes anything]*

Comment: you are welcome. Splitting names is a very common task. Now, you could for sure puzzle out a complicated formula, but it is often much better to have a pragmatic approach. Handle 95% of all in one simple step with text-to-column, then go for the exceptions. **BTW, never forget to create backups of your files!!**